# Excel chart axis values are doubling up along the axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, axis

Excel chart axis values are doubling up along the axis - how do I stop this happening?   It is in both the primary and secondary scales.   eg the axis shows 18, 20, 20, 22, 22, 24, 24, 25

Comment: This is likely due to a conflict between your data values and Excel's default axis values.  It could also include your chart type. It would help to see some sample data and know which version of Excel you're using and what type of chart.